# iOS Block swipe down

Tags: ios, objective-c, translation, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to disable swipe down with `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`

Here my code :

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.scrollView];
    // Check for horizontal and up gesture
    if (fabsf(translation.y) > fabsf(translation.x) && fabsf(translation.y) > 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

The horizontal is correctly blocked but not the swipe down. Do you have any idea how I should write this condition ?

Comment: Is the if statement called or not?

Comment: Yep it works for the horizontal condition.

Comment: What I mean is: Does the if statement execute when it is supposed to (and not execute when it isn't supposed to)?

Comment: @NobodyNada  Yes it is.

Comment: i dont really know what you are aiming for, but just note that `fabsf(translation.y) > 0` will always be true, unless the y-translation is exactly 0, which i dont expect to be often the case since a perfectly horizontal is pretty rare

Comment: Actually if I swipe up the translation y is negative and when I swipe down the translation y is positive that's why i'm trying to block _positive translation_ :) @luk2302

Comment: then change the condition to `translation.y < 0` that way your condition is true if the y-translation is negative - do you actually know, what `fabsf` does?

Comment: Thanks it works! `fabsf` gets the absolute value, no ? It's true I dont need that here. Sorry i'm new in coding ;)

Comment: If that solution works, consider adding it as an answer to your own post and to accept it.

Comment: Now just mark it as answered, and then it will be even more clear to others who will stumble upon this question later that it was solved ;)

Comment: @ErikDolor sorry but I have to wait for 2 days before being able to mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guys suggested it in the comments - **here the solution** :

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.scrollView];
    // Check for horizontal and Up gesture
    if (fabsf(translation.y) > fabsf(translation.x) && translation.y < 0 )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

**Then I came up with something maybe better in term of UX :**

Directly in the `PanGestureRecognizer` I added :

```
if (translation.y > 0) {
            panedView.center = CGPointMake(YOUR_CENTER.x, YOU_CENTER.y + translation.y /10);
        }
```

It creates a very small translation and make the whole animation more smooth for the user.

Thanks!